# URL Routing in ASP.NET webform

Tags: .net, webforms, url-routing

I would like to root the below url

```
http://domain/hotels/london?id=123&count=3&...
```

My `RouteConfig` file below

```
routes.MapPageRoute("hotels_city", "hotels/{city}", "~/hotels.aspx")
```

But I'm getting `HTTP Error 500.0`. How can i solve this?

Comment: whats the error message? 500 means internal server error. if your route is wrong you should only get 404 which is not found

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the reason. There was some error in relative path of script files. I corrected and now the problem solved.